# ENMTML: "error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'coef': variable lengths differ"

Tags: r, modeling

I am working in environmental niche modelling (ENM) for 3 species on the R package ENMTML (https://github.com/andrefaa/ENMTML), it is off-CRAN.

Description of objets:

- **envt** is a directory path to a folder with 19 bioclimatic (.asc) variables, directly from Worldclim website cutted to the study area
- **occ_t1** is a directory path to a tab delimited text file of three columns with species name, longitude, and latitude data. Example of .txt (firts rows):
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGBI.png)

My lines of code were:

```
ENMTML(
  pred_dir = envt,
proj_dir = NULL,
occ_file = occ_t1, 
sp= 'species',
x= 'x', 
y='y',
min_occ = 20,
thin_occ = NULL,
eval_occ = NULL,
colin_var = c(method= 'PCA'),
imp_var = TRUE,
sp_accessible_area = c(method='BUFFER', type= '1'),
pseudoabs_method = c(method= 'ENV_CONST'),
pres_abs_ratio= 1,
part = c(method='BOOT', replicates= '1', proportion= '0.7'), 
save_part = FALSE, 
save_final = TRUE,
algorithm = c('SVM', 'RDF', 'MXD'),
thr= c(type= 'MAX_KAPPA'),
msdm=NULL, 
ensemble= c(method='PCA'),
extrapolation=FALSE
)

Checking for function arguments ...
Loading environmental variables ...
RasterBrick successfully created!
Performing a reduction of variables collinearity ...
Warning in if (tolower(e) %in% c(".tiff", ".tif")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Loading and processing species occurrence data ...
Results can be found at:  
C:/Users/Result
Generating masks for species acessible area  ...
Performing partition of species occurrence data ...
Total species to be modeled 3
Fitting Models....
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'coef': variable lengths differ (found for 'data')"
```

Can anyone help me? I have no idea how to resolve this error.

Error in { :
task 1 failed - "error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'coef': variable lengths differ (found for 'data')"

Thank you very much! Regards

Comment: can we please have a [mcve], and at least let us know what package `ENMTML` comes from ... ? (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422243/what-could-be-causing-enmtml-occurrence-data-problem-undefined-columns-selecte)

Comment: Sorry, i'm new here. Hope it's better now!